# query execution : warn user if multiple records are to be deleted

Tags: delphi

How do you warn a user (with a confirmation dialog) that the query he is about to execute will delete more than one record ?

'DELETE FROM...WHERE...' can encompass one or more records so I am wondering how to warn the user he is going to delete more than one record.

Comment: You encapsulate the process within a single user action and wrap that action in a prompt. This is extremely trivial programming practice. We don't know what exactly you mean by "multiple records" - there's endless ways of identifying such information.

Comment: What I am asking is to tell the user deleted records will be more than one.

Comment: Your question is badly phrased. You ask how to warn the user. But what you meant to ask was how to find how many records were deleted. So you might add to the query this `SELECT @@DELETED` and then read that value from your query. Of course we don't know what SQL flavour you use, how it's wrapped etc. If the user does not want to delete, roll back.

Comment: @David That's a possibility, as there are many possibilities with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to prompt the user...

```
case MessageDlg('Are you sure you wish to delete multiple records?', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) of
  mrYes: begin
    //Continue
    DoWhatNeedsToBeDoneToDeleteMultipleRecords;
  end;
  mrNo: begin
    //Don't continue
  end;
end;
```

For example, you may do...

```
if ADOQuery1.RecordCount > 1 then begin
  PromptToDeleteMultipleRecords;
end;
```

So to sum it all up, your code might look something like...

```
if ADOQuery1.RecordCount > 1 then begin
  case MessageDlg('Are you sure you wish to delete multiple records?', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) of
    mrYes: begin
      //Continue
      DoWhateverNeedsToBeDoneToDeleteMultipleRecords;
    end;
    mrNo: begin
      //Don't continue
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The code above does not tell the user if its one or multiple records. One record - its Ok. But if its multiple, then the warning.

Comment: @user3181689 Well you haven't told us enough information to know what you're really expecting. What type of database? What data library are you using? What drivers? Can we see some code to understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to warn the user that the query is about to delete MORE than ONE record. It would be nice if the query could first do me a count of records about to be deleted but that's optional...Want to learn basic first.

Comment: @user3181689 Have you looked at the documentation for whatever library you're using? We don't know what you're using, I'm only assuming. What you're asking is extremely basic stuff.

Comment: does the recordcount apply also for a table beforedelete event ?

Comment: After seeing David's comment on your question, I'm not sure my answer addresses what you really meant to ask.

Comment: Why is this not working :procedure TDataModule.MYTABLEBeforeDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if  MYTABLE.RecordCount > 1 then begin
  case MessageDlg('Are you sure you wish to delete multiple records?', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) of
    mrYes: begin
      MYTABLE.First;
      while not MYTABLE.Eof do begin
      MYTABLE.delete;
      MYTABLE.Next;
    end;
    end;
    mrNo: begin
      MYTABLE.Cancel
    end;
  end;
end;
end;

Comment: "if MYTABLE.RecordCount > 1 "  You may be misunderstanding what the RecordCount means:  it is the number of records *in* the table, not the number of records that will be, or have been, deleted from it.  If what you're trying to tell the user is "There is more than one record in this table and all of them are about to be deleted." then fine.

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't be trying to delete records from a table in its BeforeDelete event.  This will cause the BeforeDelete event to occur again (and again).

Answer (score 1):

This is to address your "Why is this not working :procedure TDataModule.MYTABLEBeforeDelete(DataSet: TDataSet)"? question in your comment, not as an alternative to the answer @JerryDodge has given you.  Asking a question like that, you need to explain what it is exactly which is happening (or not) which differs from your expectations.

Don't try and do deletions inside the BeforeDelete event.  Do it before the operation starts, e.g. as shown below (CDS1 is the name of my dataset).

Btw, if you really do want to interrupt a dataset operation, call Abort.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res : Integer;
begin
  if CDS1.RecordCount < 1 then exit;
  if CDS1.RecordCount > 1 then begin
    Res := MessageDlg(Format('You are about to delete %d records.  Proceed?',
      [CDS1.RecordCount]),
      mtConfirmation,
      [mbYes, mbNo],
      0);
    if Res = mrYes then begin
      CDS1.First;
      while not CDS1.Eof do begin
        CDS1.Delete;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else begin
    CDS1.Delete;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that;

1. way; get record count before delete;

   ```
   query.close;
   query.sql.text := ' Select Count(*) as recCount From Table Where tableId > 15 ';
   query.open;
   if messagedialog(query.fieldbyname('recCount').asstring + ' record will be deleted! Continue?', mtConfirmation, mbyesno, 0) = mrYes then
     Begin
       query.close;
       query.sql.text := ' Delete From Table Where tableId > 15 ';
       query.execsql;
     end;
   ```
2. way; use transections if the database that you use supports

   ```
   query.connection.BeginTrans;
   query.sql.text := ' Delete From Table Where tableId > 15 ';
   i := query.execsql;
   if messagedialog(inttostr(i) + ' record will be deleted! Continue?', mtConfirmation, mbyesno, 0) = mrYes then
     query.connection.CommitTrans
   else
     query.connection.RollbackTrans;
   ```

For first way, please remember if the user waits long time after message appear the total record count might be changed if the database is being used by multiple users.

I don't have Delphi on this pc so there might be syntax errors.